# Список из spinner

Tags: android, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализуется список из spinner. Просто в интернете много примеров  с одним `spinner`, а вот поместить их неограниченное количество, скажем, в `ListView` нету(

Answer (score 1):

Пишете [свой адаптер](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter), вставляете в item списка spinner, готово!